# Equivalent of `outer` with list or vector output

Tags: r, vectorization

With `map` you can apply a function to each pair of arguments :

```
> mapply(rep, 1:4, 4:1)
[[1]]
[1] 1 1 1 1

[[2]]
[1] 2 2 2

[[3]]
[1] 3 3

[[4]]
[1] 4
```

I expected to do something similar but for each combination of arguments with `outer` but it does not work because the output of `outer` should be a 4x4 array in this example :

```
> outer(1:4, 4:1, rep)
Error in dim(robj) <- c(dX, dY) : 
  dims [produit 16] ne correspond pas à la longueur de l'objet [40]
```

Is there some R function (base R ideally) to do this as easily as `mapply` or `outer` ?

The expected output in this minimal example should look like this :

```
> c(mapply(rep, 1:4, 4), mapply(rep, 1:4, 3), mapply(rep, 1:4, 2), mapply(rep, 1:4, 1))
 [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 1 2 3 4
# Or
> c(rep(1:4, each = 4), rep(1:4, each = 3), rep(1:4, each = 2), rep(1:4, each = 1))
 [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 1 2 3 4
```

I could use a combination of `expand.grid` and `apply` but I expect that there is some easier solution :

```
> unlist(apply(expand.grid(1:4, 4:1), 1, function(x) rep(x[1], x[2])))
Var1 Var1 Var1 Var1 Var1 Var1 Var1 Var1 Var1 Var1 Var1 Var1 Var1 Var1 Var1 Var1 Var1 Var1 
   1    1    1    1    2    2    2    2    3    3    3    3    4    4    4    4    1    1 
Var1 Var1 Var1 Var1 Var1 Var1 Var1 Var1 Var1 Var1 Var1 Var1 Var1 Var1 Var1 Var1 Var1 Var1 
   1    2    2    2    3    3    3    4    4    4    1    1    2    2    3    3    4    4 
Var1 Var1 Var1 Var1 
   1    2    3    4
```

---

Based on 李哲源 Zheyuan Li' reply (for the record) : with `outer` and `Vectorize` you obtain a unusual object : a matrix with each element being a list :

```
> res <- outer(1:4, 4:1, Vectorize(rep.int))
> class(res)
[1] "matrix"
> typeof(res)
[1] "list"
> res
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,] Integer,4 Integer,3 Integer,2 1   
[2,] Integer,4 Integer,3 Integer,2 2   
[3,] Integer,4 Integer,3 Integer,2 3   
[4,] Integer,4 Integer,3 Integer,2 4
```

You can `unlist` it to obtain a vector or remove the dimension attribute to obtain a regular list :

```
> unlist(res)
 [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 1 2 3 4
> 
> dim(res) <- NULL
> # res <- c(res)  # equivalent
> res[1:5] # show the first 5 elements of the list
[[1]]
[1] 1 1 1 1

[[2]]
[1] 2 2 2 2

[[3]]
[1] 3 3 3 3

[[4]]
[1] 4 4 4 4

[[5]]
[1] 1 1 1
```

In this case `outer(1:4, 4:1, Vectorize(rep.int))` works but in many situations you will need `outer(1:4, 4:1, Vectorize(rep.int, SIMPLIFY = TRUE))`.
See [李哲源 Zheyuan Li answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39066356/how-to-perform-pairwise-operation-like-in-and-set-operations-for-a-list-of-v) for more explanations

Here, the output of myfun is a length 2 vector --> works only with `SIMPLIFY = FALSE` because you need that the result of each run of `myfun` is a length 1 list

```
> myfun <- function(x, y) c(sum(x,y), mean(x,y))
> myfun(1,4)
[1] 5 1
> res <- outer(1:4, 4:1, Vectorize(myfun, SIMPLIFY = TRUE))
Error in dim(robj) <- c(dX, dY) : 
  dims [produit 16] ne correspond pas à la longueur de l'objet [32]
> res <- outer(1:4, 4:1, Vectorize(myfun, SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
>
```

Here the output of myfun is a length 2 list --> works only with `SIMPLIFY = FALSE`

```
> myfun <- function(x, y) list(sum(x,y), mean(x,y))
> myfun(1,4)
[[1]]
[1] 5

[[2]]
[1] 1

> res <- outer(1:4, 4:1, Vectorize(myfun, SIMPLIFY = TRUE))
Error in dim(robj) <- c(dX, dY) : 
  dims [produit 16] ne correspond pas à la longueur de l'objet [32]
> res <- outer(1:4, 4:1, Vectorize(myfun, SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
>
```

Here the output of myfun is a length 1 list containing a length 2 vector 
--> works with both `SIMPLIFY = FALSE` and `SIMPLIFY = TRUE`

```
> myfun <- function(x, y) return(list(c(sum(x,y),mean(x,y))))
> myfun(1,4)
[[1]]
[1] 5 1

> res <- outer(1:4, 4:1, Vectorize(myfun, SIMPLIFY = TRUE))
> res <- outer(1:4, 4:1, Vectorize(myfun, SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
```

Comment: What about `unlist(sapply(4:1,function(t) rep(1:4,each = t)))` ?

Comment: sorry I have been unexpectedly unavailable... Both answers seem good but yours is more straightforward...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `FUN = Vectorize(rep.int, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)` inside `outer`, to get a matrix list.

Related: [How to perform pairwise operation like `%in%` and set operations for a list of vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39066356/4891738)

Comment: I never saw a matrix of list before ! I didn't even know that it was possible.  Really instructive ! Thanks. I'm just not sure to understand why you need `SIMPLYFY = FALSE`

Comment: OK, Now I think I understand the `SIMPLIFY = FALSE` part I think . I had to read several times the provided link and make my own examples to understand it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

If we need an option with `Map`

```
unlist(do.call(Map, c(f= rep, unname(expand.grid(1:4, 4:1)))))
#[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 1 2 3 4
```