# "dims [product xx] do not match the length of object [xx]" error in using R function `outer`

Tags: r

```
x <- 1:9
names(x) <- paste0("x",x)
y <- 2:5
names(y) <- paste0("y",y)

fun1      <-function(a, b) {paste(class(a),b, sep = "**")} #works
funError  <-function(a, b) {paste(class(a),class(b), sep = "**")} #does not work with outer
funNoError<-function(a, b) {paste(a,class(a),class(b),b, sep = "**")}  #works with outer  

funError(1,2) #is a valid function
outer(x, y, "funError") # fails
outer(x, y, "funNoError") # works
```

**Q1**: Why does `outer(x, y, "funError")` not work ?

> Error in dim(robj) <- c(dX, dY) : 
>     dims [product 36] do not match the length of object [1]

**Q2**: Why does `outer(x, y, "funNoError")` work ? Its pretty similar.

- The only difference I can see is that every "result" of `funError` is identical (`"numeric**numeric"`).
- If having the same value all the time is the problem: Why does this here work?

`outer(rep(0,7), 1:10, "^")`

---

Okay, I get it:

```
lol  <- function(a,b) {"lol"}
lol_v<- Vectorize(lol)

outer(x, y, "lol")   # fails with same Error
outer(x, y, "lol_v") # works as expected
```

Comment: interestingly, also `funNoError2 <- function(a,b){paste(class(a),b,sep="**")}` works...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I often explain `outer(x, y, FUN)` when both `x` and `y` are vectors with the following:

```
xx <- rep(x, times = length(y))
yy <- rep(y, each = length(x))
zz <- FUN(xx, yy)
stopifnot(length(zz) == length(x) * length(y))  ## length = product?
z <- matrix(zz, length(x), length(y))
```

`funError` fails because `zz` has length 1, while `funNoError` does not because "recycling rule" has been applied when you paste `a` (a vector with length > 1) and `class(a)` (a length-1 vector).

This is illustrative as you will see why `outer(1:5, 1:5, "+")` works but `outer(1:5, 1:5, sum)` fails. Basically, `FUN` must be able to process `xx` and `yy` **element-wise**. Otherwise, wrap `FUN` with a sugar function called `Vectorize`. More details are given later.

Note that "list" is also a valid mode of a vector. So `outer` could be used to some non-standard things like [How to perform pairwise operation like `%in%` and set operations for a list of vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39066356/4891738).

---

You can pass matrices / arrays to `outer`, too. Given that they are just vectors with an "dim" attribute (optionally with "dimnames"), how `outer` works does not change.

```
x <- matrix(1:4, 2, 2)  ## has "dim"
y <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3)  ## has "dim"

xx <- rep(x, times = length(y))  ## xx <- rep(c(x), times = length(y))
yy <- rep(y, each = length(x))  ## yy <- rep(c(y), each = length(x))
zz <- "*"(xx, yy)
stopifnot(length(zz) == length(x) * length(y))  ## length = product?
z <- "dim<-"( zz, c(dim(x), dim(y)) )

z0 <- outer(x, y, "*")
all.equal(z, z0)
#[1] TRUE
```

`?outer` explains the code above in plain words.

```
 ‘X’ and ‘Y’ must be suitable arguments for ‘FUN’.  Each will be
 extended by ‘rep’ to length the products of the lengths of ‘X’ and
 ‘Y’ before ‘FUN’ is called.

 ‘FUN’ is called with these two extended vectors as arguments (plus
 any arguments in ‘...’).  It must be a vectorized function (or the
 name of one) expecting at least two arguments and returning a
 value with the same length as the first (and the second).

 Where they exist, the [dim]names of ‘X’ and ‘Y’ will be copied to
 the answer, and a dimension assigned which is the concatenation of
 the dimensions of ‘X’ and ‘Y’ (or lengths if dimensions do not
 exist).
```

The word "vectorized" is **NOT** [the most discussed one in R on performance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51681978/4891738). It means "vectorizing the action of a function":

```
## for FUN with a single argument
FUN( c(x1, x2, x3, x4) ) = c( FUN(x1), FUN(x2), FUN(x3), FUN(x4) )

## for FUN with two arguments
  FUN( c(x1, x2, x3, x4), c(y1, y2, y3, y4) )
= c( FUN(x1, y1), FUN(x2, y2), FUN(x3, y3), FUN(x4, y4) )
```

Some functions say `"+"`, `"*"`, `paste` behave like this, but many others don't, say `class`, `sum`, `prod`. The `*apply` family functions in R are there to help you to vectorize function action, or you can write your own loop to achieve the same effect.

---

Another worth reading good-quality Q & A: [Why doesn't outer work the way I think it should (in R)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18110397/4891738)

Answer (score 2):

I think this comes because the resulting matrix from outer expects to be the same dimensions as your inputs, however, class(a) is only length 1, therefor the matrix dimensions do not match. Try

```
funError2 <- function(a,b){paste(rep(class(a), length(a)),rep(class(b), length(b)), sep = "**")}
outer(x,y, "funError2")
#>    y2                 y3                 y4                
#> x1 "integer**integer" "integer**integer" "integer**integer"
#> x2 "integer**integer" "integer**integer" "integer**integer"
#> x3 "integer**integer" "integer**integer" "integer**integer"
#> x4 "integer**integer" "integer**integer" "integer**integer"
#> x5 "integer**integer" "integer**integer" "integer**integer"
#> x6 "integer**integer" "integer**integer" "integer**integer"
#> x7 "integer**integer" "integer**integer" "integer**integer"
#> x8 "integer**integer" "integer**integer" "integer**integer"
#> x9 "integer**integer" "integer**integer" "integer**integer"
#>    y5                
#> x1 "integer**integer"
#> x2 "integer**integer"
#> x3 "integer**integer"
#> x4 "integer**integer"
#> x5 "integer**integer"
#> x6 "integer**integer"
#> x7 "integer**integer"
#> x8 "integer**integer"
#> x9 "integer**integer"
```

Created on 2018-09-13 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).