# R: Use outer() on user-defined function

Tags: r, vectorization, user-defined-functions

I want to use a user-defined function with the `outer` function. I want to use every combination of the two vectors' elements as arguments for my function `myfun`.

```
v1= c(30, 60, 100)
v2 = c(30, 60, 100)

myfun = function(x, y){
  rt = unlist(Vectorize(retimes::rexgauss)(n = x, tau = y, mu = 500, sigma = 50))
  ks = ks.test(rt, "pnorm", mean(rt), sd(rt))$p.value
  shap = shapiro.test(rt)$p.value
  z = skew(rt) / sqrt(6/length(rt))
  ztest = pnorm(-abs(z))*2
  results = c(ks, shap, ztest)
  names(results) = c("ks", "shapiro", "ztest")
  return(results)
}

outer(v1, v2, myfun)
```

If I do it like this, I get this error:

> Error in dim(robj) <- c(dX, dY) : dims [product 9] do not match the
>   length of object [3]

I want to avoid looping over all the elements of my two vectors. How can I use the outer function here? How do I vectorize my udf properly?

Comment: Add desired result. Read the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: ["dims \[product xx\] do not match the length of object \[xx\]" error in using R function `outer`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52317124/4891738); [Why doesn't outer work the way I think it should (in R)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18110397/4891738)

Comment: Max, the purpose of `outer` is to produce the outer-product of two vectors. The [definition of the outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) says that two vectors of length `n` and `m` will produce a matrix of dimensions `n x m`. Each of your `x` and `y` will be a vector of length `n*m` (9 here) and *must* output a vector of the same length.

Comment: @r2evans @李哲源  I understand that `outer` might be the wrong function for my task. Is there an alternative function which could help here? I tried using `sapply(v2, function(y) sapply(v1, function(x) myfun(x, y)))` but it's not too elegant and in its output it is hard to see which row corresponds to which combination of the vectors' elements.

Comment: What is your expected output? Just a vector of three numbers? Are you expecting your function to be called once for each combination, or once with all combinations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use `outer`, some basic "requirements":

1. the function will take two vectors all at once (as shown below); whether it chooses to do vectorized work on them or work on them individually is up to you;
2. it must return a vector of the same length as `x` (and `y`); and
3. you must expect the output as a `matrix` of dimensions `length(x),length(y)`.

Interpreting that these are not all true for you, we move on. "The right function" depends on how you want the model to be run. A companion function to `outer` is `expand.grid` (and `tidyr::crossing`, the tidyverse version), in that it creates the same combinations of the supplied vectors. For instance:

```
outer(c(30,60,90), c(30, 60, 100), function(x,y) {browser();1;})
# Called from: FUN(X, Y, ...)
# Browse[2]> 
x
# [1] 30 60 90 30 60 90 30 60 90
# Browse[2]> 
y
# [1]  30  30  30  60  60  60 100 100 100
```

and

```
eg <- expand.grid(x=c(30,60,90), y=c(30, 60, 100))
eg
#    x   y
# 1 30  30
# 2 60  30
# 3 90  30
# 4 30  60
# 5 60  60
# 6 90  60
# 7 30 100
# 8 60 100
# 9 90 100
```

(which you can then access as `eg$x` and `eg$y`).

Some options:

1. if you want your function to be called once (as with `outer`) with two arguments, and it will figure out what to do:

   ```
   eg <- expand.grid(x=c(30,60,90), y=c(30, 60, 100))
   do.call("myfunc", eg)
   ```

   Note that if given `character` arguments, it will (similar to `data.frame`) create `factor`s by default. It does accept the `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` argument.
2. if you want your function to be called for each pair of the vectors (so 9 times in this example), then do one either

   ```
   myfunc(eg$x, eg$y)
   ```

   if the number of vectors is known. If not, then using `eg` from above, then

   ```
   do.call("mapply", c(myfunc, eg))
   ```

   should work. Depending on the output, you can preclude it from "simplifying" the output (i.e., force a `list` output) with

   ```
   do.call("mapply", c(myfunc, eg, SIMPLIFY=FALSE))
   ```

Comment: I had been experimenting with `expand.grid` but was missing the `do.call` part. Your second approach worked for me! Thank you.

Comment: It can seem odd to call `do.call("mapply", ...)`, but it's a good way (imo) to deal with variable-length lists, as `eg` can be if the number of columns is variable.