# Apply a function over pairwise combinations of arguments

Tags: r, mapply

I'm not that familiar with R so this question may have already been answered but I just probably couldn't understand the answer so any links to other threads would be helpful.

I'm looking for a way to basically do the R equivalent of the c program

```
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
        arr[i][j] = func(i+1,j+1);
    }
}
```

I tried

```
x <- mapply(func, 1:12, 1:9)
```

but it only passes (1,1), (2,2), (3,3) ... into `func`. How can I pass all pairwise combinations of the vectors 1:12 and 1:9 into `func`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work: `outer(1:12, 1:9, func)`?

If not, use `matrix(apply(expand.grid(1:12, 1:9), 1, func), 12, 9)`.

Background: ["dims [product xx] do not match the length of object [xx]" error in using R function `outer`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52317124/4891738)

Answer (score 0):

```
sapply(data.frame(t(expand.grid(1:12, 1:9))), function(v) func(v[1], v[2]))
```

`expand.grid` creates all combinations as data frame rows.
`t` transposes the result, and I take it as a `data.frame` (`t` returns annoyingly a matrix ... even when applied on `data.frame`s ...) and `sapply` over it.
Since `sapply` treats data frames like a list of column values,  I get columnwise (actually rowwise - after application of `t` transpose ...) listing of the data frame conent. These actual row-vectors are taken from the function and the function `func` applied on the two values produce. So at the end, we took every pairwise combinations possible and entered it to function(v) ...